# How many versions of the Japanese-translated Harry Potter books are there?

Tags: harry-potter, books, translation

I have on me a physical copy of the Japanese translation of the first Harry Potter book, translated by Yuko Matsuoka, first published 1999.

The Kindle version has the same translator but was published in 2015 by Pottermore. Just from reading the first couple of sentences you can already see some changes to the text. There's also more [furigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furigana)<sup>1</sup> in the Pottermore version.

I have also seen in Japan a version of the book with more furigana than the physical copy that I have on me now. Not sure if it's identical to the Pottermore version as I don't have it on me.

Does anyone know the full list of all the versions?

(Note I'm not concerned about any changes to the cover or size of the books, just the actual text contained within).

---

<sup>1</sup> [Furigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furigana) (振り仮名) is a Japanese reading aid, consisting of smaller kana, or syllabic characters, printed next to a kanji (ideographic character) or other character to indicate its pronunciation.
— Wikipedia

Comment: Do you feel that the two texts you've seen are actually wholly different translations? Or is is possible that the translation with more furigana used is based on the original translation, but revised for younger readers? That may be a useful distinction.